# How do I provide a client certificate when connecting to a server in Windows 8.1 with StreamSocket?

Tags: python, wcf, windows-8.1, stream-socket-client

When looking at the StreamSocket API in Windows 8.1, it doesn't appear that there's any way for a `StreamSocket` to provide a client certificate for the server to validate, in either `UpgradeToSslAsync` or `ConnectAsync`. Is there anyway to do this at all in Windows without using WCF ? I'm setting up a Python server and it seems like there'd be no easy way to use WCF with  a Python server (or any other non-WCF service, for that matter)

Comment: Can you use HTTP? You can try `Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ClientCertificate`

Comment: This is for a server that's intended to be very specialised. I can use http, but I'd prefer not to have the overhead